# Drawing circles with ImageMagick without unwanted offsets

Tags: imagemagick

The following command:

```
 convert -size 96x96 canvas:transparent -fill red -draw "circle 48,48 48,0" output.png
```

draws the following image:

[image: off-center]

If you observe the right and bottom sides, you will see that the circle is slightly clipped at the image's edges.

On the top and left edge, it is flush to the image's boundaries.

I am struggling to get a result where the circle's boundaries correspond perfectly to those of the image, with no clipping occurring.

This is what it should look like (image created in Photoshop):

[image: correct]

No permutation of the parameters seems to improve the result, and I'm confused as to why this is occurring at all.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
convert -size 96x96 canvas:transparent -fill red -draw "circle 47.5,47.5 47.5,0" output.png
```

And have a read of [this explanation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#control_coordinates).